# Visual Studio became failed to support dwproj files

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Encounered a problem with exisiting multidimesional project. After opening it in VS2017 (native  for it), the project became incompatible... Messsage in solution explorer: application not installed.
Checked UpgradeLog2.htm:
The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=659044&projecttype=D2ABAB84-BF74-430A-B69E-9DC6D40DDA17

"Microsoft Analysis Services Modeling" already installed, either SSDT did. Which direction to dig?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reinstalled SSDT https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer
2. Opened project (it was still incompatible)
3. Right click on project in solution viewer - reassemble